# Scanning an int array from file

Tags: c

Suppose there is a file named 'input' which looks like this:

```
             Joyle       Hughes       5    6 7 6 9 10
              Marc        Gasol       3    9 10 8
              Yuki     Yamamoto       5    10 10 10 10 10
             Milan      Francis       4    9 9 9 8
```

The first column stores names, the second surnames, the third one stores data about how many tests the student has taken, and the numbers following are the grades they received on each one of them.

We also have a struct 'Student' defined like this:

```c
struct Student {
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int nr;
    int arr[50];
};
```

My task is to store all of the data from the file into a struct Student array, and calculate the average grade for each student.
What I'm having trouble with is actually storing the grades in an int array. Here is how I tried:

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct Student a[1000];
    int len= function(a,1000);

    int i,j;
    int sums[1000]= {0};
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<a[i].nr; i++)
            sums[i]+=a[i].arr[j];
    }
    float avg[1000];
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        avg[i]=(float)suma[i]/a[i].nr;
    }
    FILE *fout=fopen("output.txt","w");
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<len; k++)
        fprintf(fout,"%15s %15s %f\n",a[i].name,a[i].surname,avg[i]);
    fclose(fout);


    return 0;
}

int function(struct Student *s,int len)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
        exit(1);
    int i=0;
    while((fscanf(fp,"%7s%12s%8d",s[i].name,s[i].surname,&s[i].nr))==3) {
        int k;
        for(k=0; k<s[i].nr; k++) {
            fscanf(fp,"%2d",&s[i].arr[k]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}
```

When I try to print the average grades, all I see are values of 0.0000 which, I guess is due to a fault in the loops I used to store the data.

Comment: I forget if you need to include whitespace between your `fscanf()` format string. I would start by checking that. Also, Why are you using `%2d` in your loop? Shouldn't it just be `%d`?

Comment: You should post the rest of the code, the posted code has no information that can help identify the problem.

Comment: @JonathanWood no, whitespace is not the problem, I don't think it is.

Comment: @EmirShemafied what headers did you include? Where is `vel` declared?

Comment: Minor: Rather than `"%7s%12s%8d"`, use `"%19s%19s%d"`.  `name` and `surname` are 20 and no real need to limit input width of `nr`.

Comment: @EmirShemafied did you solve the problem? did you know [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors:

1. You don't include any header files, which causes the compiler to assume that all standard library functions return `int` and hence they don't work as expected. In your case the worst one would be `fopen()`.
2. You call `function()` in `main()` without providing a declaration for it.
3. `vel` is undeclared, which I assume is because you didn't copy and paste the code from the editor to your question.
4. You iterate with the variable `j` and increment `i`<sup>1</sup> here

   ```
   for(j=0; j<a[i].nr; i++)
   ```
5. You iterate with the variable `k` and use `i` in the loop body<sup>1</sup> here

   ```
   int k;

   for(k=0; k<vel; k++)
       fprintf(fout,"%15s %15s %f\n",a[i].name,a[i].surname,avg[i]);
   ```

This is your code fixed to work properly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Student {
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int nr;
    int arr[50];
};

int function(struct Student *s,int len);

int main()
{
    struct Student a[1000];
    int            i;
    int            sums[1000] = {0};
    int            len;
    float          avg[1000];
    FILE          *fout;

    len = function(a, 1000);
    for (i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0 ; j < a[i].nr ; j++)
            sums[i] += a[i].arr[j];
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
        avg[i] = (float)sums[i] / a[i].nr;
    fout = fopen("output.txt","w");
    if (fout == NULL)
        return -1;
    for (i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
        fprintf(fout,"%15s %15s %f\n", a[i].name, a[i].surname, avg[i]);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}

int function(struct Student *s,int len)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int   i;

    i  = 0;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(1);
    while ((fscanf(fp, "%19s%19s%d", s[i].name, s[i].surname, &s[i].nr)) == 3)
    {
        int k;
        k = 0;
        while ((k < s[i].nr) && (fscanf(fp, "%2d", &s[i].arr[k]) == 1))
            k += 1;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return i;
}
```

---

1<sub>Be careful when copying and pasting code.</sub>

Comment: Well, thank you. Btw, I was working on this problem using abbreviations for words in my native language, and obviously I forgot to change it at certain places when I pasted the code here.

Comment: There's two things I am still uncertain of. When using the while loop to scan the file, does the pointer fp 'move' along as the file is being scanned? And how does it know when to read from a new line?

Comment: 1. The pointer doesn't move, `FILE *` is a structure and it has a position marker, which does move, 2. It doesn't know, the `fscanf()` format string does the job, it scans the file matching the directives one by one and ignores whitespace characters except for a couple of directives, since `'\n'` is considered white space, then that's how you are reading lines. About the variable names that were wrong, change them in your editor using the search/replace feature.